# Git - Having a private local "fork"

Tags: git, fork, local, private

I wish to make some private customizations to a public open-source project from GitHub,

How should I make a "private local fork" of it? Just clone it to my computer and commit locally, or there's another type of Git command which fits the process better?

Notice, that I would still like to receive updates from the public repository, while keeping my changes.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process you've described is exactly correct.

Clone the repo, make changes locally. You won't be able to push unless you have write access, but you'll still be able to pull changes from the remote repo, and merge them with the changes you're making.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath You can't help but create a local branch when you clone. You don't need to create a "local" branch to work off of, you'll already have a local branch, probably named "master".

Comment: @meager: ... and because branching and merging is so cheap in git, people tend to work on branches (while working on different features), and typically don't work on "master". Just because "master" already exists, it doesn't mean there's no reason to create a new branch.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The emphasis on "local branch" was yours. I'm simply stating that the branch you're already on *is* a "local branch".